# UNIX file commands

Tags: unix

The command cat file1 >> file2 is used to :
a: Overwrite the file file2 by file1
b: Append the content of file1 in file2 and if file2 does not exist will create a new file file2 and copy the content.
Which one is correct option?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Option (b) is correct. The `>>` means APPEND.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your shell.

If you use zsh and the CLOBBER option is not set, the command will append the content of file1 to file2 if file2 exists and cause an error otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with (b)

- The cat command reads one or more files and prints them to standard
  output.
- The operator `>` can be used to combine multiple files into
  one.
- The operator `>>` can be used to append to an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Option b. is correct as you can notice when trying...

Have a look at [this](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucat.htm) and [that](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Step_by_Step_Guide/s1-navigating-usingcat.html)